# Advertencia de vip scanner php

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo este codigo y el vip scanner me da una advertencia pero no logro darme cuenta cual es el problema, alguno tiene idea?

```
public function callback($data = false) {
    if (false !== $data) {
        $message = serialize($data);
        //wp_mail( 'pbearne@gmail.com', $message );
    }
}
```

Error:

```
An endpoint needs to return something, I'd also suggest adding a type hint to the `$data` parameter
```

Comment: Si pruebas con `if ( $data !== false)`

Answer (score 0):

> Prueba:
>
> - Devolver (`return`) algo al finalizar la función `callback`.
> - y documentar el parámetro `$data`

Por ejemplo:

```
/**
 * @param array $data Arreglo con la info a ser enviadada por mail
 * @param bool  $data Si es `false` no se enviara info por mail
 */
public function callback( $data = false ) {

    if ( false !== $data ) {
        $message = serialize( $data );
        // wp_mail( 'pbearne@gmail.com', $message );
    }
    
    // Devolver algo (An endpoint needs to return something)
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Toda la razon!, es que como el codigo no esta bien ordenado no me percate! borrare los comentarios